# Use node require inside a method called using requireJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, amd, commonjs

Is it possible to use the default node `require` function in a file that has been called through `requirejs`?

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
  //...
  var Schema = require(DaoPublic._schemasDirectory + schemaFilename);
}
```

I always get `ReferenceError: module is not defined`, I also tried to load the schema using requireJs, same, because the file itself is coded as CommonJs, not AMD compatible.

Any solution?

Note that the loaded schema is in CommonJS and I need to keep this way, since it's used by several DAO, some in AMD and other in CommonJs. (Funny part)

*Example of requested file (schema):*

```
var userSchema = {
    /**
     * User Login, used as id to connect between all our platforms.
     */
    login: {
        type: String,
        match: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        notEmpty: true,
        unique: true,
        check: {
            minLength: 4,
            maxLength: 16
        }
    }
};

module.exports = userSchema;
```

Comment: Are you checked [CommonJS notes](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html)?

Comment: I read a lot about requirejs and didn't find anything yet. My temporary (and maybe only solution) was to create two classes instead of one, one used though CommonJs and another through AMD.

Comment: `ReferenceError` is the error you get when the code tries to access an unknown identifier. Start Node.js at the command line, type `foo`, and you'll get `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`. There's no mention of a `module` variable in the code you show us. If `ReferenceError` is raised by your own code, then please show in your question which line of code raises it and provide some context for it.

Comment: I guess you're not familiar with CommonJs syntax, the `module.exports` is the way used to export the code (class/function/var/...) with CommonJs. So, at the end of my `schema.js` file I have `module.exports = schema`, where `schema` is a var that contains the schema itself. See this gist: https://gist.github.com/Vadorequest/7cea3d064eb9c7990923

Comment: @Vadorequest The issue here is not whether *I* can guess right (which I *did*) but to bring your question up to the standards of SO. It must be formulated so that it does not require people to *guess*. First, a guess, as educated or evident as it may be, can *still* be wrong, which means that the people who posted answers based on the guess have wasted their time. Second, *if possible*, the question should be readily understandable by people who do *not* have the expertise to make an educated guess. You can do this very easily here by adding to the body of your question the info I asked for.

Comment: I actually didn't think that was useful in the first place, because that was obvious to me, but I see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code is set so that RequireJS *is able* to find the CommonJS module by itself. However, when RequireJS is running in Node and cannot find a module, it will call Node's `require` function, which is what you need. So it is possible (with RequireJS) to have an AMD module use Node's `require` but the trick is getting RequireJS to not see the module in the first place.

#### Proof of Concept

Here's a proof of concept. The main file named `test.js`:

```
var requirejs = require("requirejs");

function myRequire(path) {
    if (path.lastIndexOf("schemas/", 0) === 0)
        path = "./" + path;
    return require(path);
}

requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "schemas": "BOGUS"
    },
    nodeRequire: myRequire
});

requirejs(['foo'], function (foo) {
    console.log(foo);
});
```

The file `foo.js`:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
  return require("./schemas/x") + " by way of foo";
});
```

The file `schemas/x.js`:

```
module.exports = "x";
```

If you run it with `node test.js`, you'll get on the console:

```
x by way of foo
```

#### Explanation

I'm calling this a "proof of concept" because I've not considered all eventualities.

The `paths` setting is there to throw RequireJS off track. `BOGUS` must be a non-existent directory. When RequireJS tries to load the module `./schemas/x`, it tries to load the file `./BOGUS/x.js` and does not find it. So it calls Node's `require`.

The `nodeRequire` setting tells RequireJS that Node's `require` function is `myRequire`. This is a useful lie.

The `myRequire` function changes the path to add the `./` at the start before calling Node's require. The issue here is that for some reason RequireJS transforms `./schemas/x` to `schemas/x` before it gives the path to Node's `require` function, and Node will then be unable to find the module. Adding back the `./` at the start of the path name fixes this. I've tried a whole bunch of path variants but none of them worked. Some variants were such that RequireJS was able to find the module by itself and thus never tried calling Node's `require` or they prevented Node from finding the module. There may be a better way to fix this, which I've not found. (This is one reason why I'm calling this a "proof of concept".) Note that I've designed this function to only alter the paths that start with `schemas/`.

#### Other Possibilities

I've looked at other possibilities but they did not appear to me very promising. For instance, customizing `NODE_PATH` would eliminate `myRequire` but such customization is not always doable or desirable.

Comment: Interesting way to "hack" the `require` method used by `requireJs`, but the problem here is different, it does find the file, but cannot "parse" it, because the file uses a CommonJs notation instead of the expected AMD. The problem is that, from an AMD file, I try to require, using node.js native `require` a CommonJs file, but because it's inside an AMD file it fails instead of require the file, like it would have done if the file that contains the require call has been loaded using CommonJs.

Comment: My answer is solving exactly what you describe in your comment here. I've reworded the first paragraph a little bit to emphasize some things that may have needed more emphasis. Like for instance you say "it does find the file". Well, yes, and that's precisely what you must avoid to get the result you want, and exactly what my solution does (prevent RequireJS from finding the CommonJS module, so that Node loads it instead).

Comment: I need requirejs to work to find most of my files, I now understand your solution, but I don't think that's a good idea, that will break my code somewhere else :/

Comment: This solution is designed to affect only the loading of modules from `./schemas`, and this path could be changed to something else if needed or made as deep as needed (e.g. `./schemas/commonjs/`). It is not clear at all why it should cause issues elsewhere in an application.

Comment: Because I forgot you check the path. That's why I thought that would change all my path, my bad. I think our solution would work, but that's not something I'll do, the code is complicated enough without custom looking file require to make fail requireJs.
Maybe a solution I would use one day, not today, I prefer keep the code sweet and clean. But thanks!

Comment: Here is the answer from the github requirejs repo. https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/1119

Comment: When I tried what James suggests, I got the same error as the original one you were getting. Also, his comment about sync vs async `require` calls is correct *except* when running in Node. To check, I've modified the `foo` module I have in my answer to load the schema like this: `var path = "./schemas/x"; return require(path) + " by way of foo";` and it works fine. I don't think he quite understood what was the problem you ran into. (By the way, the upvote on your question is mine.)

Comment: I didn't try his solution yet. Yeah, maybe he didn't understand the context of the question. Thanks. (I need to make a try)